# How to make elements traslate(y) with different values on scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand how can I get an effect like this, look at the different cards:
https://trends.fjordnet.com/trends/

I would like to understand how can I make those divs change their velocity during their Y translation.

Thank you for helping me..

Comment: There are many jQuery/JS plugins available for this e.g. scrollorama, scrollmagic, skrollr etc.

Comment: It could be like a parallax effects?

Comment: yes you can achieve parallax effect also using any of these plugins.